# spring cloud AWS sendAndReceive

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, amazon-sqs

I need to send and receive SQS message as I do it in rabbitmq. So I need to do that synchronously. 
The issue is, if I use @SqsListener in spring boot,the method never invoked if it has a signature other than (String s). Any other signature does not simply work, method is not triggering.

My config is:

```
@Bean
    public QueueMessagingTemplate queueMessagingTemplate() {
        return new QueueMessagingTemplate(amazonSQSAsync());
    }

    @Bean
    public AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync() {
        return AmazonSQSAsyncClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey)))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainer simpleMessageListenerContainer() {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer msgListenerContainer = simpleMessageListenerContainerFactory()
                .createSimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        msgListenerContainer.setMessageHandler(queueMessageHandler());
        return msgListenerContainer;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory simpleMessageListenerContainerFactory() {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory msgListenerContainerFactory = new SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory();
        msgListenerContainerFactory.setAmazonSqs(amazonSQSAsync());
        return msgListenerContainerFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public QueueMessageHandler queueMessageHandler() {
        QueueMessageHandlerFactory queueMsgHandlerFactory = new QueueMessageHandlerFactory();
        queueMsgHandlerFactory.setAmazonSqs(amazonSQSAsync());
        QueueMessageHandler queueMessageHandler = queueMsgHandlerFactory.createQueueMessageHandler();
        List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> list = new ArrayList<>();
        HandlerMethodArgumentResolver resolver = new PayloadArgumentResolver(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());
        list.add(resolver);
        list.add( new HeaderMethodArgumentResolver(null, null));
        queueMessageHandler.setArgumentResolvers(list);
        return queueMessageHandler;
    }
```

and receiver is:

```
@SqsListener(value = {"${cloud.aws.end-point.uri}"}, deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.ALWAYS)
    public void receive(String message)  {
        System.out.println("Inside receive: " + message);
    }
```

If this method has any other signature, it will not even be triggered. What should I do to retrieve a raw aws Message here to use in AwsSQSResponder?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `@Payload` annotation?

```
@SqsListener(value = {"${cloud.aws.end-point.uri}"}, deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.ALWAYS)
    public void receive(@Payload String message)  {
        System.out.println("Inside receive: " + message);
    }
```